# Call gapi.auth2.init many times with different client_id

Tags: angular, google-authentication, google-api-js-client, clientid

I have a sigle web page (angular6 app) when a user admin can create different google accounts. I use gapi to get a backoffice code with grantOfflineAccess. This need a GoogleAuth instance so I do a gapi.auth2.init(options) before to set the new client_id to the options, but in the official documentation says that once I call init method, It use always the same client_id.

The only solution is to reload the page (F5).
Even if the client_id is incorrect, I can't let the user change it.

It doesn't work to call to authorize, because I need the grantOfflineAccess code to send to the api and this is a GoogleAuth method.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand why you need to switch between multiple client_id. This ID should be linked with your app and not with the user account. Could you give me more details ?

Comment: You're right. I recently talk with the product owner telling that. We can create multiple google accounts with the same app. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I know is using `gapi.auth2.authorize`, which allows:

> Several Client IDs are used within the same page

Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeparams_callback

But I think the `init()` method is the safest way to go.